# Japan's docomo service email

Tags: html, email

I'm working in Japan and my task is related with sending html email to docomo email (example edokiyo_hari@docomo.ne.jp).

My problem is my images don't show anything and my links don't work.

```
<body data-parentid="0">
 <div>編集するとき文にクリックしてください。<a href="https://www.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx">テスト</a></div>
 <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<ol>
  <li>私</li>
  <li>音さん</li>
</ol>
</body>
```

I don't want to use deco email.

How can I do it? (at least make link to work).

Comment: The MSDN link doesn't work because it's an invalid link. It must start with `http(s)://` or at least `//` if it's not on the same domain (which in an email is meaningless to begin with).

Comment: @deceze        it is valid link.

Comment: Oh yes? Try clicking it: https://jsfiddle.net/ev5ghtms/1/

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Thank you for taking the time to write it for me, im very very sorry . But the problem is docomo's mail service  .